# How can I compile a regex in Elasticsearch 5x's Painless syntax

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-painless

I have a need to compile a regex defined by a parameter in Painless.

My initial assumption would be that I could do something similar to the following:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(params.myPattern);
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown call [compile] with [1] arguments on type [Pattern].
```

Perhaps there is another way to convert a string into a Pattern object in Painless?

Comment: I see you asked the question on the github, so just linking it for others: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28755#issuecomment-367504055

Comment: Indeed! Thank you!